# How to combine nodes by alternating data structures? - Java

Tags: java, nodes

I am given two data structures of Nodes, and I am supposed to combine them into one single Node with alternating data structures. The data structures may or may not be of equal lengths.

I have already attempted this problem and I have checked over my code, but it still isn't correct. I have written other methods that I use in this one particular method, so I will post the code for those too. I came up with my method by looking at examples of how the data organization for this particular problem works.

Get the head of the Node list:

```
public static <E> Node<E> getHead(Node<E> current) {
    Node<E> head = null;
    while (current != null) {
        head = current;
        current = current.previous;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Get the number of Nodes in the data structure:

```
public static <E> int countNodes(Node<E> current) {
    int count = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        count++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note that I have tested these two methods (getHead and countNodes) and they have proven to be correct. I have posted them to see if they are missing something.

The Node class itself was written by my instructor and has been tested to be correctly written

```
public static class Node<E> {
    public Node<E> next;
    public Node<E> previous;
    public E data;

    public Node(E d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (next == null)
            return "";
        return data + ", " + next.toString();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Node<E> node = (Node<E>) o;
        if (node == null)
            return false;
        Node<E> current = this;
        while (current != null && node != null) {
            if (!current.data.equals(node.data)) {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.next;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return current == null && node == null;
    }
}
```

Finally, the method that I am having problems with: (Updated with edits)

```
public static <E> Node<E> combineNodes(Node<E> current, Node<E> current2) {
    Node<E> newNode = null;
    int currentSize = countNodes(current);
    int current2Size = countNodes(current2);
    int size = Math.max(currentSize, current2Size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i <= currentSize - 1) {
            Node<E> node = new Node<E>(current.data);
            newNode.next = node;
            node.previous = newNode;
            newNode = newNode.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (i <= current2Size - 1) {
            Node<E> node = new Node<E>(current2.data);
            newNode.next = node;
            node.previous = newNode;
            newNode = newNode.next;
            current2 = current2.next;
        }
    }

    return getHead(newNode);
}
```

Again, I have looked through the code and I feel like it should work. Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrong?

**Edit**

I should have included the test case that I was given. My instructor is using the JUnit test case library for the assignment. This is the test case that I have to pass:

```
@Test
public void combineNodesTest1() {
    LinkedData.Node<String> node = makeStructure(10); // Makes a data structure of Nodes from "Fred 0" to "Fred 9"
    LinkedData.Node<String> node2 = makeStructure(10);
    LinkedData.Node<String> ret = new LinkedData.Node<String>("Fred 0");
    ret.next = new LinkedData.Node<String>("Fred 0");
    LinkedData.Node<String> r = ret.next;
        for(int i = 1; i<10;i++) {
        r.next = new LinkedData.Node<String>("Fred "+i);
        r = r.next;
        r.next = new LinkedData.Node<String>("Fred "+i);
        r = r.next;
    }
    LinkedData.Node<String> answer = LinkedData.combineNodes(node, node2); // Method that I wrote
    assertEquals(ret, answer);
}
```

The makeStructure() method is correctly written.

**Edit 2**

I have updated the code to actually link the nodes together, but it is still wrong. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong now.

Thanks, 
Steward

Comment: I'm missing something, what is the result now? What's your code doing? Output? And what should it do? Provide some examples please

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, you don't change any of pointers (next, previous) in your `combineNodes` method. You only traverse the structure. What is missing in the first `if` is

```
newNode = current;
newNode.next = current2;
current = current.next;
```

and then the following in the second `if`

```
newNode = current2;
newNode.next = current;
current2 = current2.next;
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, and now I've updated the code. It's still wrong and I still can't seem to figure out why.